# When passing a JSON string to PHP the return value is NULL

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am learning JSON. I've read around to find a solution to what i could be doing wrong but I seriously cant find it. I am trying to pass a JSON strnig to PHP and see what it returns... my current code is always returning null no mater what i do.
I feel that i am doing all by the book to make it work. but obviously i must be missing something

Could anyone tell me why is the `$arrayData` is always returning `NULL` ?

I can see that what is currently posting is `mydata=%7B%22name%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22regno%22%3A%22hola%22%7D`
if i dont use `JSON.stringify()` then i see the data sending as `mydata=[object Object]`

PHP

```
<?php
$mydata = $_POST['mydata'];
$arrayData = json_decode($mydata);
var_dump($arrayData);
 ?>
```

HTML

```
<script>
function lol () {
            var name = "yes";
            var regno = "hola";
            var arrayData = {"name":name,"regno":regno};
            console.log(arrayData);

            $.ajax({  
                      url: "algo2.php"
                      ,type: "POST"
                      ,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
                      ,data: {'mydata=' : JSON.stringify(arrayData)}
                      ,success : function(response) {                            
                        alert(response);            
                      }
                      ,error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError);
                      }
                });
}

</script>
</head>
<button onclick="lol()">Try it</button>
```

OPTION 2

```
function lol () {
            var name = "yes";
            var regno = "hola";
            var arrayData = {"name":name,"regno":regno};
            console.log(arrayData);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayData)); 
            $.ajax({  
                      url: "algo2.php"
                      ,type: "POST"
                      ,data: 'mydata=' + arrayData
                      ,success : function(response) {                            
                        alert(response);            
                      }
                      ,error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError);
                      }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a. Remove the header thing
b. Change the key to `mydata` without the equal sign

```
var name = "yes";
var regno = "hola";
var arrayData = {"name":name,"regno":regno};

$.ajax({  
      url: "index.php"
      ,type: "POST"
      ,data: {'mydata' : JSON.stringify(arrayData)}
      ,success : function(response) {                            
        //alert(response);            
      }
      ,error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //alert(thrownError);
      }
});
```

Comment: I already tried using 'mydata' instead of 'mydata=' and i get the same resutls.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and check in firebug that there is actually something sent to the server

Comment: if i print_r ($_POST) i get Array
(
)

Comment: Meaning the request is empty. The problem is not PHP, but somewhere in  `Javascript`. Try removing the headers thing. The content you are sending supposed to be normal form data. Try without the headers and keep print_r'ing the post array until it gets populated.

Comment: I did. Still not getting it. the only solution is taking the "mydata=" off the field and sending and array... which is an option but then... it should be possible to do what i am trying to do

Comment: You tried incorrectly.  
1. Remove the header thing  
2. change the key to `mydata`, without the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `urldecode()` the data first if you have it stringified:

```
$mydata="%7B%22name%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22regno%22%3A%22hola%22%7D";
$json= urldecode($mydata);
$array = json_decode($json, true); //use the argument true if you want the object to be returned as an Associative array
print_r($array);
```

If you don't used the second argument in json_decode(), it will be returned as an object:

```
$mydata="%7B%22name%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22regno%22%3A%22hola%22%7D";
$json= urldecode($mydata);
$object = json_decode($json);
echo $object->name;
```

Comment: It doesnt work even if I do urldecode($_POST);. But i shouldnt have to do urldecode... I havent seen a single JSON example using that

Comment: Maybe is the thing on the header deceze answered, I just tried the code I pasted and it works, I mean, it returns the array/object correctly

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mydata=%7B%22name%22%3A%22yes%22%2C%22regno%22%3A%22hola%22%7D
> ```

This is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, not `application/json` data. Yet you specify in your headers that it is JSON data. PHP will not decode that data and won't populate the `$_POST` array.

Either send actual JSON data with the JSON header and decode it yourself (from `php://input`), or omit the header, send urlencoded data (as you are) and let PHP populate the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried "headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',} ,data: 'mydata=' +arrayData" but still doesnt work. Could you provide an example on how to send it as JSON please? thanks

Comment: What you are sending and what you claim to be sending doesn't match! `"mydata=..."` is **urlencoded** format, not JSON. Don't claim to be sending JSON when you are not. It doesn't matter that the value of `mydata` is JSON, it is wrapped in a urlencoded format. Keep the urlencoded data, just remove the `headers` declaration which incorrectly specifies you're sending JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending JSON to php you need to read the raw input, like this:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (!empty($input)) {
    $arrayData = json_decode($input, true);
    var_dump($arrayData);
}
```

also in jquery I use this for json requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ dataType:"json", mimeType:"application/json", contentType:"application/json"})
```

Comment: I just replaced my PHP file with exactly that and it still return null and i took the "header" our of the JS